# Why does "cut" command skip first line in this "while read line" loop?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script, and I need to take the second field of every line in a file, and save them in another file. I know there are many possible ways to do this, BUT, I tried first using `while read line; do`, and I got stuck. Now, I really want to know what is happening.
For example, input file would be:

```
line1   11111
line2   222222
line3   333
line4   4444
```

(The field separtor is "\t").

This is what I was doing:

```
inputfile=$1
cat $"inputfile" | while read -r line
    do
    cut -f2 >> results_file
    done
```

The problem is, the output would be:

```
222222
333
4444
```

(skipping the first line)

I´ve alredy tested hundreds of modifications, and tried to used other commands instead of `cut`(like, `sed`, `grep`...). I would appreciate some help, or someone pointing me in the right direction.
Thank you very much!

Comment: try to convert your file with dos2unix i thought you file is under windows line break format

Comment: You can use echo to print each line, e.g. `while read -r line; do echo "$line" | cut -d$'\t' -f2; done < input.txt > results.txt` or you could just use awk e.g. `awk '{print $2}' input.txt > results.txt`. There are so many ways to do what you want - maybe some more info will help us to help you

Comment: The thing is, I needed a loop, because field 2 of my input are actually URLs: I have to generate a file with field 1 of this inpupt in a column, and an specific info downloaded from its respective URL in another column. In order to know which downoloaded file corresponds with each original URL, I thought it was best to do all directly with a loop. I hope I expleained myself well enough... Also, I had alredy done what you suggest, but without de "$" in de option `cut -d$'\t'`. Does it mean to use "\t at the end" as a separator? By the way, with that, it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the variable `$line` set by `read`. Try instead

```sh
inputfile=$1
cat "$inputfile" | while read -r line
    do
    echo "$line" | cut -f2 >> results_file
    done
```

In your original code, the `while` loop is actually run only once, not four times; try putting `echo 'Hello!'` in the loop to your original code. You would see the message only once, not four times. I guess, without `echo "$line" |` part, `cut -f2 ...` part consumes the pipe away.

That is, your `while` loop first consumes the first line of the stdin and puts this line in the variable `$line`, leaving the next three lines for later use. But `$line` is never used. Instead, the remaining three lines are consumed by the command `cut`.

> All commands within a command group are within the scope of any redirections applied to a command group (or any compound command):
>
> — https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands

> The pipe operator creates a subshell environment for each command.
>
> — https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput

We can interpret the quotes as "the stdin to your while loop (i.e., the output of `cat "$inputfile"`) is accessed by `cut`, unless you sever its access by creating a new subshell e.g., by another pipe `echo "$line" | ...`."

By the way, you can just use `cut -f2 "$inputfile" >> results_file` without the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your comment `Does it mean to use "\t at the end" as a separator` - no. You're confusing what was suggested, `$'\t'` with `'\t$'`. `$'\t'` means "the literal tab character generated from the escape sequence `\t`".

You also said in your comment your real 2nd fields are URLs to be curled. You shouldn't be using a UUOC and cut anyway, here's how to really do this:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key url; do
    val=$(curl "$url" | whatever)
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$key" "$val"
done < "$inputfile" > results_file
```

Replace `whatever` with whatever command you use to produce the output you want from the `curl` output.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use it!